# Finding $N_\epsilon$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

$x_n = \frac{2n}{n^3 + 1}$. Find $N_\epsilon$ such that $|x_n| < \epsilon$   $ \forall N > N_\epsilon$.
Here are my thoughts:

$|\frac{2n}{n^3 + 1}| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{2n}{n^3 + 1} < \epsilon$

$\frac{2n}{n^3 + 1} < \frac{2n}{n^3} \Rightarrow \frac{2n}{n^3} < \epsilon  $

$\frac{2}{\epsilon} < n^2 \Rightarrow \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\rceil < n \Rightarrow N_\epsilon = \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\rceil$

Comment: you forgot to include $\epsilon$ in your square root

Comment: @John11 Thanks! I've fixed it. And apart from that everything is ok?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine. You have found your $N_{\epsilon}$. All that is left is to use that to write your proof formally. That is: Fix an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, say that you take $N_{\epsilon}= \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\rceil$ then write your inequalities that lead you to something smaller than $\epsilon$